# Android Notification defaults

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I've used the newer `NotificationCompat.builder`, with `NotificationChannel`, and I was able to show a notification correctly (also in Android O).

The Android Documentation says to set a style which I've done with:

`android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.InboxStyle`

But the notification is showing with **no sound**, **no vibrate** and **no flashing the light**.

**My question is:** there is a simple way to set  users default configuration for notifications? I am not looking for custom sound, vibrate and lights. I just wanna to support the default configurations.

The complete code

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context, channelId)
     .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
     .setContentText(contenteText)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notfication)
     .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle())
     .build();
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: what is your target API?

Comment: Api 26 (Android O)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setDefaults(param)` method to manage vibro, sound and light behaviour

To enable set `Notification.DEFAULT_ALL` as parameter, to disable `~Notification.DEFAULT_ALL` . You can setup each visualization element by its own parameter flag

Comment: What about default sound notification?

Answer (score 0):

To set default vibrat and light configurations in notificaitons:

```
setDefaults(param)
```

To set default sound configuration:

```
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
```

Comment: wats param in `setDefaults(param)`

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
Uri defaultUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
```

and then use ther Notification-Builder's `setSound(Uri uri)`-method

Comment: What about vibrate and lights?

Comment: If you set your phone on vibrate, then it does vibrate for incoming notifications. I'm not sure about the lights, my phone's lights never worked so I don't know the effect.

Comment: Is not vibrating even with phone set to vibrate

Comment: There seems to be a method `enableLights()`. Try this one - [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel.html#enableLights(boolean))